# Using a method that accepts blocks and can return truthy or falsey values

Tags: ruby, methods, reduce

So, I am back with another question! I have learned how to accept arguments with blocks but I need now to place a block in my method (I think).

Here is what I have to do, it's a generalized `reduce` method with the following tests going through it:

```
describe 'my own reduce' do
  it "returns a running total when not given a starting point" do
    source_array = [1,2,3]
    expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo + n}).to eq(6)
  end

  it "returns a running total when given a starting point" do
    source_array = [1,2,3]
    starting_point = 100
    expect(reduce(source_array, starting_point){|memo, n| memo + n}).to eq(106)
  end

  it "returns true when all values are truthy" do
    source_array = [1, 2, true, "razmatazz"]
    expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo && n}).to be_truthy
  end

  it "returns false when any value is false" do
    source_array = [1, 2, true, "razmatazz", false]
    expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo && n}).to be_falsy
  end

  it "returns true when a truthy value is present" do
    source_array = [ false, nil, nil, nil, true]
    expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo || n}).to eq(true)
  end

  it "returns false when no truthy value is present" do
    source_array = [ false, nil, nil, nil]
    expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo && n}).to eq(false)
  end
end
```

Here is my code:

```
def reduce(element1, starting_point = 0, &block)
  element1.reduce(starting_point, &block)
end
```

Which passes 4 out of the 6 tests. But the last part requires checking the values in the `source_array` and if any are truthy return true or if any are falsey, return false. I tried putting in the follow block along with the `reduce` method:

```
def reduce(element1, starting_point = 0, &block)
  element1.reduce(starting_point, &block){ |x, y| if x || y = true; p true; else p false; end}
end
```

If you look at the tests, you can see it will pass one array with 'true' and one with 'false' and I need it to work for all the 6 tests.

Please, any explanation has been helping me greatly.

Comment: Congrats for the question. We don't see complete specs every day.

Comment: I wonder why you do not use the build in method: `all?`, `any?`, `none?` and `sum`?

Comment: Thanks, trial and error. I noticed I needed to provide the full details to get both the answer and explanation I need to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify a default value for `starting_point` which will work for every use case, since you want to use numbers & booleans.

If you don't specify a `starting_point`, `reduce` will simply use the first [element as starting_point](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
def reduce(elements, starting_point = nil, &block)
  if starting_point.nil?
    elements.reduce(&block)
  else
    elements.reduce(starting_point, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: I see, that was very helpful. I will remember that one!

Comment: @RoderickCardenas: Be sure to check mrzasa's answer too, specifically the 1st point.

Answer (score 5):

1. If your job is to write your own `reduce`, don't use `Enumerable#reduce` inside. You can use `Enumerable#each` or `for`/`while` loop
2. You can pass a block to another method just as you do it with `method(arg1, arg2, &block)`.
3. You can call your block with `#call`, e.g. `block.call(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Appreciate the details! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the failing test should specify a `starting_point`.

```
  it "returns true when a truthy value is present" do
    source_array = [ false, nil, nil, nil, true]
    - expect(reduce(source_array){|memo, n| memo || n}).to eq(true)
    + expect(reduce(source_array, false){|memo, n| memo || n}).to eq(true)
  end
```

The meaning of `||` depends on the left-hand side. `Integer#||` is different from eg. `FalseClass#||`. They are different methods.

Comment: Specs all seem reasonable. It means the tests should be made to pass by simply touching the code, no changing the specs.